# Change Docker for windows to use another VM besides MobylinuxVM

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

Setup **Docker Desktop for Windows**.

Created a new VM Create a Docker Machine ....

```
docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "External" manager11
```

Ran through all the tutorials on this machine and everything is working

```
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/
```

Now I would like to change my Local Docker client to use this newly created machine instead of the MobylinuxVM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`docker-machine env`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/) can output the environment for cmd or powershell. 
The output includes comments with the command to set the environment in your shell.

CMD

```
C:\> docker-machine env --shell cmd manager11
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:/Users/matt/.docker/machine/machines/manager11
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=manager11
REM Run this command to configure your shell: 
REM     @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd manager11') DO @%i
```

Powershell

```
PS C:\> docker-machine env --shell powershell manager11
$Env:DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = "1"
$Env:DOCKER_HOST = "tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
$Env:DOCKER_CERT_PATH = "C:/Users/matt/.docker/machine/machines/manager11"
$Env:DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME = "manager11"
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# & docker-machine env --shell powershell manager11 | Invoke-Expression
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, My docker deployment is at the office so I will not be able to verify your answer until Monday. But your answer looks correct.

Comment: I tried running docker-machine env --shell powershell manager11. Docker.exe is still pointing at Mobylinuxvm not at the new vm.

Comment: I did not realize I needed to run the commented out code from the env command. I updated your answer to reflect this.